# jQuery remove specific text from elements and add it to an current element?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Lets say I have several Divs and a group of serial numbers. When I click on Div, there's a panel I can pass some numbers into the div; And When I click on the 2nd div, I can pass the same numbers into current one but will remove duplicated numbers from the others.

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3,...,10]

<div id="panel">
<button>1</button>
<button>2</button>
...
<button>10</button>
</div>

<div id="column">
<div class="card">1, 2</div>
<div class="card active">3, 4, 5, 6, 7</div>
<div class="card">8, 9, 10</div>
</div>
```

I came up with a problems: Passing the numbers to current div will remove all the others (including those never selected).

```
$("#panel button").on("click", function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("selected");
        checkSelected()
})

function checkSelected(){
    var arr = [];
    $("#column .card.active").html("");
    for(var i = 0 ; i < $("#panel button .selected").length; i++){
        var num = $("#panel button .selected").eq(i).text()
        arr.push(num)
    }
    arr.sort(function(a, b){
        return a - b;
    });

    for(var j =0; j < arr.length; j++){
        var div = $("#column .card.active");
        var res = '<p>'+arr[j]+'</p>';
        div.append(res);
        // remove others...
        $("#column .card").not( ".active").find("p:contains("+arr[j]+")").filter(function () {
            return $(this).length > 0;
        }).remove();
    }
}
```

**Updated:**
Just made a sample here [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/longlife0428/dLh0qkr3/)

Anyone? Any help? really appreciate it.

Comment: You've lost me a bit to be honest. Can you rephrase a bit?

Comment: Can you create a work snippet with your current code?

Comment: Please check the above link, its quite similar :p

Answer (score 0):

Maybe check wether the .remove() at the very end doesn't just discard all the numbers?